# Linear Differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to determine whether there is normal linear differentiation equation $a_2(x)y'' + a_1(x)y' + a_0(x)y = 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $u_1, u_2 \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $u_1(x) = x, u_2(x) = sinx$ at each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ are both solutions to own equation on $\mathbb{R}$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $u_1$ being a solution gives that for all $x$
$$ 0 = a_2(x) u_1''(x) + a_1(x) u_1'(x) + a_0(x) u_1(x) = a_1(x) + a_0(x)\cdot x $$
hence we must have $a_1(x) = -a_0(x)x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $u_2$ being a solution gives 
$$ 0 = a_2(x) u_2''(x) - a_0(x)x u_2'(x) + a_0(x)u_2(x) = -a_2(x)\sin x - a_0(x)x\cos x + a_0(x)\sin(x) $$
hence 
$$ -a_2(x)\sin x = a_0(x) (x \cos x - \sin x)$$
which is (for example) fulfilled if $a_0(x) = -\sin x$ and $a_2(x) = x\cos x - \sin x$. By the above, we are forced to let $a_1(x) = x\sin x$, leaving us with the equation
$$ (x\cos x - \sin x)y''(x) + x\sin x \cdot y'(x) - \sin x \cdot y(x) = 0 $$
of which both $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions.